# iOS how to add different attributes to multiple occurrences of same substring

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I want to make an NSAttributedString with different attributes for each of the two occurrences of the same substring.

```
NSString *text = @"ABC & ABC";
NSString *substring = @"ABC"
NSMutableAttributedString *attStr= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

NSRange range = [[attStr string] rangeOfString:substring];
```

I want to set different attributes for each occurrence of the substring using the  method
 `[attStr addAttributes:attributes range:range]`. However, no matter how many times I run it, only the first occurrence of substring changes the attributes.

Is there a way to let the `addAtributes:` know to look for substring whose attributes haven't been set yet?

Comment: You need to get the two different ranges for the substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can calculate how much time word is repeated.

```
NSUInteger count = 0, length = [@"ABC & ABC" length];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
    while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        range = [self.dateTime rangeOfString:@"ABC" options:0 range:range];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could get an array of multiple matches using iteration over an NSRegularExpression:

```
NSString *string = @"ABC & ABC";
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"ABC" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);

if (!error) {
    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
    }];
}
```

Then get the range from result.range property.